# How to display large numbers of pins using Google Maps API on iPhone App over populating screen with red pins - suggestions on improved User Interface

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps

I am developing an iPhone app that involves populating a Google map with lots of location points around the UK.

There are over 10,000 points and when the user scrolls out each point is fixed to the map based on a lat./long position, and every time the user changes their zoom amount it has to reload the pins on the page.

As you can imagine trying to load 10,000 pins on an iPhone screen every time you move the map, takes time to load and makes the app unusable.

Here is a screenshot of how over populated the app becomes:
http://www.wreckfinder.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/photo-8.png

I am having trouble deciding on a good way to display the data in a more clean and friendly way.

Potential solutions:

- Grid view
  I think a design like this would work, but it seems to complex to easily create:
  http://marinetraffic.com/ais/

this website groups areas of the map and explains how many pins are within an area, then once you're zoomed in enough, it populates the map with the points for viewing.

- Display a maximum number of pins
  the other idea I have is to only show a maximum of 500 pins at any one moment. So once the user is zoomed in at a level where there are under 500 pins it will display them. but there is a problem, I cannot find a way to know how many pins are showing on the iPhone at any moment, it would seem you can only control the database of pins, you cannot know at which zoom level / location the user is looking at the map.
- split the database into sections
  for example split the screen into 9 boxes - 3x3 and separate the database into ~1000 pins per box then when the user clicks on a region they only get a display of these pins in that region, then have to go back in order to get view of any further pins.

---

From above I would ideally like to use 1. or 2.
2. would seem the most simple,

I would be grateful if you can help explain how to achieve 2. or have other possible easy simple solutions for better displaying these pins!

Comment: What about grouping them together as you zoom out and splitting them apart as you zoom in, like the Photos app when you view photos by location

Answer (score 4):

Group your pins in 1 pin. And on different zoom levels ungroup them, this way for example on the zooming level of the UK, you will have for example 50 pins(for reagions for example). Zooming in to a region, will ungroup its pin to its child pins. This is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did in my app to solve a similar issue: Basically, don't draw the pins automatically; make the user ask for them.

1. Mark the center of the map with a dot or target icon.
2. Add a button at the bottom "Find All Locations Within 10 Miles" of the center of the map
3. Tapping the button iterates through your database (ideally in a background thread); if within 10 miles of center, drop a pin (hopefully, your database can be ordered by lat/lon so you don't have to go through all 10,000)

The cool extra was I'd build on that database of pins, so as the user moves around the map, then asks for more locations, I just add to what's already on screen.

Shake to reset pins. =)

As you zoom in and out, you can change the mile radius (1, 5, 10, 50) but the key is to free up the map scrolling by limiting the number of pins. Good luck!

EDIT: I don't have enough rep to comment on Oleg/Zoleas approach but if you must show all 10,000 points, grouping pins is definitely the way to go. But as a UX designer, I'd ask whether it's more important for the user to find locations close to his current location vs. needing to view all the possible locations.

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg Danu said, you can group your pins. Here is an article wich talk about it. There is also some libs as examples, and the algorithm we used in our case (note that the algorithm is not trivial to implement):

http://applidium.com/en/news/too_many_pins_on_your_map/

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I've used Marker clusterer lib for this, you can find it at:

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/tags/markerclustererplus/2.1.2/examples/simple_example.html